# Upload Big ZipArchive-MemoryStream to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, stream, zip, memorystream

**TL;DR**: Is it possible to upload a big MemoryStream to Azure as chunks on the fly while zipping?

I have files which get saved into a `MemoryStream`, I add these files to a `ZipArchive` in another MemoryStream.
This MemoryStream I want to upload to an `Azure-BlockBlob-Storage` using

```
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(zipMemoryStream);
```

So far so good.
The Problem now is, that the Zip-Archive might get bigger then **8GB** which is a problem with the MemoryStream.

Is it possible to upload parts from the memory-stream as chunks to azure, and remove these bytes from the Stream?

Or is there a better approach to deal with zipArchive and azure?

For zipping I am using the class `ZipArchive` in the Package `System.IO.Compression`

Best Regards,
Flo

Comment: I assume you use Block Blob?

Comment: yes, I am using block-blobs :)

Comment: What class do you use for zipping? I belive I know how to solve this. Show your code, please.

Comment: I edited my question, I don't really have much code which I am using to zip and upload, as I said, I have Data provided in MemoryStreams, and a MemoryStream which is responsible for the ZipArchive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be not exactly what you are looking for, but did you try to do something like this:

```
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("zipped.zip");
using (var stream = new ZipArchive(blob.OpenWrite(), ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    var entry = stream.CreateEntry("entry1");
    using (var es = entry.Open())
    {
        // Fill entry with data
    }

    // Other code
}
```

When you call `OpenWrite` of `CloudBlockBlob` it creates an instance of `CloudBlobStream` that works in a different way than `MemoryStream`. `CloudBlobStream` sends data to Azure Storage Service in 4MB chunks, as far as I remember it doesn't save `old` chunks into the memory.

Comment: I guess it is exactly what I am looking for, I will try it, and give you a response, but I will accept you, thanks a lot for your quick answer