# Renew Sas for BlockBlob with Upload from Stream

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, signature

**TL;DR;** Renewing of SAS needed when using `cloudBlockBlob.OpenWrite()`? If yes, how?

This is a Follow-Up-Question to:
[Upload Big ZipArchive-MemoryStream to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302243/upload-big-ziparchive-memorystream-to-azure?noredirect=1#comment67865398_40302243)

I managed to upload the ZIP-Archive to a Blob using `blob.OpenWrite()`:

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(SAS);
using (ZipArchive zArch = new ZipArchive(blob.OpenWrite(), ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = zArch.CreateEntry("BigFile", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
    {
        SaveBigFileToStream(stream);
    }   
}
```

The Shared access Signature is supposed to be as short-lived as possible

My Question now is, how do I ensure that the SAS does not expire?
Does the upload only validate the SAS once?

Comment: This does not sound very hard to test :) Why don't you set it to like 10 seconds and see what happens? You could try doing that while you wait to see if someone knows the answer off the top of their head.

Comment: Okay, yeah thats a great idea :) but even if I knew that I would need to refresh it, I don't know how ^^, but lets hope for the best (that I dont need to renew :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the SAS doesn't expire during your uploading, since uploading of one huge file to Azure Blob Service is consist of many HTTP requests which are authenticated individually.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But how would I do it in the C# Azure-Api, is it possible to set an SasEndpoint? or how can I tell the Blob, which is currently uploading that he has a new Sas? Best Regards Flo :)

Comment: If you control the uploading process by putting pages one by one, you can renew the SAS at any time you want and use the new SAS for next request. However, if you just simply call UploadFile or UploadStream, you can't change SAS in the middle.

Comment: So I would have to change the procedure of uploading? Which means I am not able to Upload from the Stream anymore as in my code-example?

Comment: If you really want so short-lived SAS, yes, you have to rewrite the uploading procedure by putting blocks/pages one by one by yourself. Do you really  think creating a SAS with 1-2 hours lifetime is not acceptable at all?

Comment: Right now, its acceptable, but the problem is that the upload is may taking longer, which makes the whole story kind of insecure over time, so I would like to avoid it, but I guess it is not thaaaat easy to implement as my current solution :D